# Is there an alternative / plugin for Visual Studio's configuration manager?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, plugins, projects-and-solutions

I have the need to remove and rename a selection of solution/project configurations in Visual Studio. Is there a tool which will help with this?

I'm finding the built-in tool very unhelpful. For example, when I delete a configuration from a solution it will refuse to delete the related project configurations just in case they are needed elsewhere. Also renaming a solution configuration will not rename its related configurations.

There must be a better way of doing this. Are there  alternative tools out there?

Answer (score 18):

> I have the need to remove and rename a selection of solution/project configurations in Visual Studio. Is there a tool which will help with this?

*Short answer:*  **No.**

*Long answer:*  **Sort-of** (e.g., you're going to integrate "helper" tools which are incomplete, and write custom scripting/work to create/integrate into your configuration management process).

*Editorial comment:* Great question. Many people have suffered this (as noted by the "upvotes" to your question), and we all would *love* a good answer.

> I'm finding the built-in tool very unhelpful. For example, when I delete a configuration from a solution it will refuse to delete the related project configurations just in case they are needed elsewhere. Also renaming a solution configuration will not rename its related configurations.

Agreed -- the built-in tool is quite unhelpful. It is very difficult to maintain many projects-and-solutions with different configurations and sets of dependencies, especially for different target types/platforms. It has idiosyncrasies like its use of multiple GUIDs for projects, sets-of-files, and project types, which are stored in the registry, and accessed from within the `*.sln` and `*.vcproj`.

The tool will attempt to "heal" itself with these unique identifiers, un-doing your changes, and ignoring some of its own values, to "repair" connections among projects/solutions. This results in a lot of "cruft" in your registry and in your configuration files, unnecessary changes to the files if you're checking them into your version control system, and scenarios where many parts of the file will be "ignored", even though you (correctly) made those changes.

Some data like "*project name*" and "*project configuration name*" and "*project platform name*" are sometimes redundant, and sometimes not. Because of the GUIDs, this type of "external/manual maintenance" makes it very easy for your project/solution to "appear" to reference the correct project (by name), but the *wrong* project (as uniquely identified by GUID, which was resolved through a reference in the registry).

And, there is more-than-one-way to specify the *same thing* within those files, leading to confusion (especially since the `*.sln`/`*.vcproj` file ontology is not well documented, nor likely to be well documented in the future).

**In short, Visual Studio is a pretty good IDE, but terrible for build and project management / maintenance.** It seems to lack a strong central design. I concede that it is a (very) hard problem -- people have worked on "build" for decades, and IMHO state-of-the-art isn't very good. However, Visual Studio is most definitely a "design-by-committee", including cruft from evolution through major fielded revisions.

Thus, the "most correct" answer to your question is "no": Visual Studio is not designed to do what you want (e.g., maintenance of solution/project configurations in Visual Studio). However, I'm sure Microsoft's response would be, "We gave you a .NET API for you to roll your own answer and write your own tools".  However, after great research on this topic, IMHO no suitable solution exists for these types of tools using those types of APIs (although you can jump in, and with great effort, write your own tools to make that maintenance easier.)

Visual Studio 2010 gets better, but it's still not great for build and project configuration management. New APIs are helpful, but they are difficult, and IMHO not well designed. Most likely, Microsoft will never seriously address that aspect of the IDE: It is an IDE, intended for accelerated development iteration, and not intended for build-project-and-solution maintenance. (Much detail can be found on this topic if you dig deep into the MSDN forums.)

> There must be a better way of doing this. Are there alternative tools out there?

Yes, and yes: For all build systems, the issue is the "data-of-record", which is what you *want* for a configuration: These files, these defined macros, these command line arguments, this target type, etc. From that (which is checked in with your source code), the "actual" build files/scripts should be generated.

Of course, I just described [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) (which generates "build files" from a data-of-record source file), and a host of other tools. They are your best bet. In this case, CMake does a good job of generating `*.sln` and `*.vcproj` files, but not a lot of other tools will (it is somewhat hard due to the complexity within those files, and their largely not-well-documented details).

Another tool that does a pretty good job generating `*.vcproj` is [qmake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmake), (which is a good build configuration manager tool, even if you don't use the Qt libraries). Another (similar idea) is Google's "[gyp](http://code.google.com/p/gyp/)" (short for "generate-your-projects", which should generate `*.sln`/`*.vcproj` files, but I'm not sure it's ready for "prime time".

For all these tools, the work-flow implies:

1. Update the data-of-record files;
2. (Re-)generate the `*.sln`/`*.vcproj` files.
3. Use the generated `*.sln`/`*.vcproj` files in your Visual Studio IDE, or command-line build.

If you don't want an external tool, but would rather have a "plug-in" of some kind that natively operates upon your `*.sln`/`*.vcproj` files, I'm unaware of anything to help you (and I've looked).

It's not a new thought: Some tools exist to operate natively on these files (like "version migration" tools some people have written-and-shared), and some people have talked about a build system natively "camped-on" these files as the data-of-record, but these files are kind of a mess, and undocumented, and a moving-target with regards to Visual Studio versions, and don't address very well the centralized question of centralized build settings with a local-project-override, so that's really hard to do. (No such build system exists at present which is "camped-on" the Microsoft native files, other than the Visual Studio, I don't think.)

Visual Studio 2010 makes creation of such a plug-in "easier" than previous Visual Studio releases, but I don't think such a plug-in yet exists (nor do I think such a generalized plug-in has a high likelihood of success, because what you're asking for is not a priority for Visual Studio, which is principally an IDE, not a configuration manager). Rather, you'll most likely have to dig into the .NET API to write your own (non-trivial work and maintenance), or try to lean on [Visual Studio Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7f8bfy4.aspx) (but I don't think that will give you what you want).

Lastly, (off-topic), I'm writing such a tool that relies on heuristics to auto-generate and auto-maintain these types of project dependencies, and I'm currently writing-out `*.sln`/`*.vcproj` files. It's not ready for "prime-time", but I'd be interested in your specific project configuration management issues, and am willing to share the tool(s) if it proves useful to you (it's personal hobby development in C++, currently Windows, but should port to POSIX with little effort).

Comment: +100 for "not a priority for Visual Studio".  I've seen other cases where they simply defer to "Use MSBuild, it's good fer ya".  And it ends up being hard in the end.

Comment: It's nice how they preach developers to maintain their build scripts, and then write the IDE build actions to go directly against any kind of build customization.

Comment: @charley Has there been any update to this since 2011? It's been 3 versions and they still haven't made the tool any more usable.

Comment: Hi @Charley, what is the current state of the world regarding this?

Comment: Still working on generator, although it has expanded into a build system:  Goal is no config files.  If a human can "figure-out" your build products (which is possible), then a tool should be able to do the same.  Perhaps I'll have something to show next year.

Answer (score 6):

I doubt that there is a third-party extension that does exactly what you want to do. However, Visual Studio 2010 has a pretty robust set of [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) automation interfaces that allows you to customize just about any part of the IDE, including the configuration manager, configurations, solutions, projects, etc. You can use just about any language you want, including C#, Visual Basic 6.0, and C++. You can even write a macro in VBScript.

Here is a graphical overview of the [Visual Studio 2010 Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/za2b25t3(v=vs.140)).

In particular see:

[Configuration Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.configuration?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[ConfigurationManager Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.configurationmanager?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

[Configurations Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.configurations?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

[Solution2 Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.solution2?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

[SolutionConfiguration2 Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.solutionconfiguration2?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

[SolutionBuild2 Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.solutionbuild2?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

Answer (score 4):

There are also the following two extensions for Visual Studio 2015. Both are recently updated at time of writing and seem promising.

- [ProjectConfigurationManager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ProjectConfigurationManager)
- [Better Configuration Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NKnusperer.BetterConfigurationManager)

Comment: I use Better Configuration Manager still, when I have to, it's quite good.

Comment: Note that this answer is relatively **new**. It relatively does not has much time to gather many upvote.  (I also suggest adding screenshot of the extensions you recommended)

Answer (score 1):

.sln and .vcproj files are actually XML files. I often find myself editing them by hand in a text editor to perform various tasks that would otherwise seem impossible to do from the UI.

The UI often performs incomplete operations, for example when renaming a project not all entries are updated. I usually prefer to do it myself by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had to do this myself, but there are some examples of doing this in code in *[How to rename "debug" and "release" to another name like "Debugstatic" something when I using a new custom wizard RRS feed](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/5de5439a-5bd1-4a9f-aba4-b4a0e91e518e/)*.

However, you should probably also review this information:

*[Understanding Build Configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/understanding-build-configurations?view=vs-2015)*

As it indicates that carrying out such changes may cause project configurations and solution configurations to be automatically created or assigned.

If you want it as an add-in you can run, you will probably need to write your own I'm afraid.

Comment: please be careful not to post .NET 1.1 links, unless the information is specific to .NET 1.1. Otherwise readers may wind up following a chain of old links to information that is no longer the best.

Comment: @John  The build configurations link is to VS2010.  The other link is for VS2005, but includes references to getting it to work in VS 2010.  And more particularly, it pertains to the Visual Studio Object Model, not to the .NET Framework.

Comment: the build configurations link is to VS2010 because I edited it. That's the link I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Roger Willcocks' link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971481/is-there-an-alternative-plugin-for-visual-studios-configuration-manager/5812857#5812857), I stumbled upon [Carlos Quintero's](http://msmvps.com/blogs/carlosq/archive/2008/08/29/the-convoluted-build-configuration-of-the-automation-model-envdte-envdte80.aspx) blog. It is an interesting read, it seems. Among other things, it mentions difficulties faced when trying to clean up project configurations.

Glancing over Microsoft's documentation, it appears that EnvDTE80 has pretty much stayed the same since Visual Studio 2005.

---

Taking a look at [EnvDTE100](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte100.solution4.aspx)...

Comment: EnvDTE80 has stayed the same. But EnvDTE90, EnvDTE90a and EnvDTE100 have been added.

Comment: Not third party, but I've used them myself to fill holes in VS functionality. However, I think most people use VS automation for custom source control and to enhance the debugger, not for custom build management.